# Ionic 2 app over device debugging 403 error

Tags: android, google-chrome, ionic2, google-developers-console

I have trying to test my app on device an look the issues on `console log` the fallowing error appears.

> **403**. That’s an error.
>
> Your client does not have permission to get URL
>   /serve_rev/@159105/devtools.html from this server. That’s all we know.

[image]

I have updated my chrome browser and device chrome browser restarted both of them but still showing error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this command:

```
adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:chrome_devtools_remote
```

Get more information from [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging-legacy).

Edit: this command will enable port forwarding.so chrome can access to your device through this port.

Comment: Please add more detailed information on how and why the command works. Links may not resolve to the current page at some future time.

Comment: I edited this.but I think more explanation is not necessary because its one of steps for using chrome inspect.

Comment: I have a same problem . I run up command successful but when click on inpect in chrome get error that : Your client does not have permission to get URL /serve_rev/@169177/devtools.html from this server. I use visual studio emulator and browser app for test.

Comment: If you're from Iran or China use anti filter tools, it may happen when you cannot get necessary data from google developers server.